# A System of Equalities and Inequalities; Is There A Unique Solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

Suppose $m_x,M_x,m_y,M_y\in\mathbb{R}$ are known and $x_l,x_h,y_l,y_h\in\mathbb{R}$ are unknown. Does the simultaneous system

\begin{align*}
    x_l \hspace{1mm}+\hspace{1mm} x_h &\hspace{1mm}=\hspace{1mm} y_l +\hspace{1mm} y_h
\\
    m_x \hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} x_l &\hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} x_h \hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} M_x
\\
    m_y \hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} y_l &\hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} y_h \hspace{1mm}\leq\hspace{1mm} M_y
\end{align*}
have a unique solution $(x_l,x_h,y_l,y_h)$? 
Of greater interest happens to be the question: **do we have $x_l =x_h$ and $y_l=y_h$?**

I don't really even know where to begin, as this is beyond my experience in linear algebra (I've only taken the standard sophomore course).
For context, I'm an undergraduate with more familiarity with analysis than algebra. I'm trying to write an alternative proof of the fact that $\int fd\alpha + \int gd\alpha = \int (f+g) d\alpha$, but that's beside the point. This system of inequalities came up. Any advice/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the solution is not unique, unless you have special configurations of the given bounds. Also, this is more of an exercise in basic real analysis than linaer algebra.

If a solution exists at all, we have
$$2m_x \le x_l+x_h \le 2M_x$$
and
$$2m_y \le y_l+y_h \le 2M_y$$

and hence it must be true that

$$S=[2m_x,2M_x]\cap[2m_y,2M_y] \neq \emptyset.$$

I'll ignore the degenerate cases where $M_x \le m_x$ and/or $M_y \le m_y$, they don't bring anything new to the table (and fall under the special configurations I mentioned above), so I assume that the intervals whose intersection $S$ is are proper intervals with positive length.

$S$ is an interval, but it might be degenerate and just a point. Those are the 2 cases $2m_x < 2M_x=2m_y < 2My$ and $2m_y < 2M_y=2m_x < 2Mx$. In the first case, it must be that $x_l+x_h=2Mx=2m_y = y_l+y_h$ and thus $x_l=x_h=M_x=m_y=y_l=y_h$. The second case has similiar consequences, again we get $x_l=x_h=y_l=y_h$.

But again, this is a special configuration of the given bounds.

If $|S| > 1$, then $S$ is a proper interval $S=[a,b]$ with $a < b$. In this case, there are infinitely many $s \in (a,b)$ and for each of them $x_l=x_h=y_l=y_h=\frac{s}2$ is a solution. That's because

$$s \in (a,b) \subset [a,b] = S \subseteq [2m_x,2M_x]$$

and hence

$$m_x \le \frac{s}2 \le M_x,$$

and the same is true for $m_y/M_y$.

Moreover, because we chose $s$ from the open interval $(a,b)$, we do not have equality in either side of the inequality above, so we get

$$m_x < \frac{s}2 < M_x$$

That means $\frac{s}2$ is an inner point of the interval $[m_x, M_y]$ and so ther exists a $\delta_s > 0$ such that

$$m_x \le \frac{s}2 -\delta_s < \frac{s}2 + \delta_s \le M_x.$$

Now that means in the above solution $x_l=x_h=y_l=y_h=\frac{s}2$ we can replace $x_l, x_h$ with infintely many other pairs

$$x_l=\frac{s}2 -\delta, x_h=\frac{s}2 + \delta$$

for any $0 < \delta \le \delta_s$.

Absolutely the same argument can be made for $y_l,y_h$.

---

So unless you have initial bounds $m_x,M_x,m_y,M_y$ that trivially force your unknowns to be either bound of the interval, you will have infinitely many solutions, also with infinitely many of them such that $x_l \neq x_h$ and $y_l \neq y_h$.

To me it looks like what happens often when dealing with inequalities. You come to a point where you see something that would have nice consequences if it could be proven. But unfortunately, your system does generally not have a unique solution and it is not even close.

Comment: Ok I see. Applying the same argument to $y := y_l -y_h$ and $x := x_l - x_h$, omitting $s=0$ from the solution set leaves still infinitely many solutions, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thank you for being thorough, by the way, I honestly greatly appreciate it. I imagine you say real analysis because this has to do with the structure of the real numbers. However, I suspect (I'll keep thinking about it regardless), upon reading your argument for the first time, that it would work for elements $x_l,m_x,$etc. of any ordered additive group of which $\frac{s}{2}$ is a limit point, would that be accurate?

Comment: Lastly, you're definitely right that that often happens when dealing with inequalities. I'll admit this was my first time seeing a problem of this nature; is there a name for this type of problem?

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman: Yes, you'll almost always (with the qualifiactions in the answer) get ininitely many solutions with $s\neq 0$. If you have an ordered group, you probably need something about between 2 different elements always existing another element that is inbetween (in the order sense) to get similar results. Otherwise you might have discrete parts where an interval $[a,b]$ with $a<b$ only has 5 elements, or something similar. But that's not something I know much about.

Comment: That's great though, thanks again. I'll come back to this in a day or so to make sure it still makes sense.